# IBM Worklight 6.2.0.01 HTTP Adapter failed to read xml from web site with HTTPS

Tags: ssl, https, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I have a http adapter which retrieves a XML file from a website through HTTPS. The SSL certificate is a real and valid certificate, not self-signed one. It used to be fine and working for over a year.

I recently upgraded to Worklight 6.2.0.01.20150129-1911 and the adapter now  failed.

The error from Worklight Server is as below:

```
FWLSE0101E: Caused by:  [project MobileApp5062]javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticatedjava.lang.RuntimeException: Http request failed: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
    at com.worklight.adapters.http.HTTPConnectionManager.execute(HTTPConnectionManager.java:233)
    at com.worklight.adapters.http.HttpClientContext.doExecute(HttpClientContext.java:185)
    at com.worklight.adapters.http.HttpClientContext.execute(HttpClientContext.java:169)
    at com.worklight.adapters.http.HTTP.execRequest(HTTP.java:148)
    at com.worklight.adapters.http.HTTP.invoke(HTTP.java:137)
    at com.worklight.integration.model.ProcedureInvoker.invokeProcedure(ProcedureInvoker.java:57)
    at com.worklight.integration.model.Procedure.invoke(Procedure.java:166)
    at com.worklight.integration.model.InvocationContext.call(InvocationContext.java:169)
    at com.worklight.integration.model.InvocationContext.call(InvocationContext.java:38)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.worklight.integration.model.InvocationContext$DirectExecutorService.execute(InvocationContext.java:284)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at com.worklight.integration.model.InvocationContext.submit(InvocationContext.java:138)
    at com.worklight.integration.model.InvocationContextManager.submitInvocation(InvocationContextManager.java:58)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.callProcedure(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:522)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.access$100(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:61)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl$3.execute(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:417)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:76)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.invokeProcedureInternal(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:414)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.invokeDynamicProcedure(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:481)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.invokeDynamicProcedureWithEnclosingProcedureProperties(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:465)
    at com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptIntegrationLibraryImplementation.invokeDynamicProcedureWithEnclosingProcedureProperties(JavaScriptIntegrationLibraryImplementation.java:142)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:225)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:52)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._integration_js_12._c_anonymous_10(/integration.js:95)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._integration_js_12.call(/integration.js)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.RateAdapter_impl_js_20._c_getRateData_3(RateAdapter-impl.js:66)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.RateAdapter_impl_js_20.call(RateAdapter-impl.js)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.RateAdapter_impl_js_20.call(RateAdapter-impl.js)
    at com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptManager.callFunction(JavaScriptManager.java:240)
    at com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptManager.invokeFunction(JavaScriptManager.java:214)
    at com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptManager.invokeFunction(JavaScriptManager.java:194)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.AdapterManagerImpl.invokeFunction(AdapterManagerImpl.java:117)
    at com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptProcedureInvoker.invoke(JavaScriptProcedureInvoker.java:42)
    at com.worklight.integration.model.ProcedureInvoker.invokeProcedure(ProcedureInvoker.java:57)
    at com.worklight.integration.model.Procedure.invoke(Procedure.java:166)
    at com.worklight.integration.model.InvocationContext.call(InvocationContext.java:169)
    at com.worklight.integration.model.InvocationContext.call(InvocationContext.java:38)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.worklight.server.util.ProjectLocal$1RunnableWrapper.run(ProjectLocal.java:261)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:128)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:397)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:148)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:149)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:121)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:573)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:425)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
    at com.worklight.adapters.http.HTTPConnectionManager.execute(HTTPConnectionManager.java:231)
    ... 50 more
```

I've tested the adapter with two different hosts, one having a valid SSL cert issued by VeriSign (IIS) and another host having a valid SSL cert issued by Starcom (Apache). Both failed.

Supplement accordingly to Idan's comment

1. The issued happened on both local development environment with worklight studio and UAT server, both running same WL server version.
2. Web server and worklight server are hosted on different server. Not on same machine.

Comment: Two things: 1) upgrade to the latest available iFix from IBM Fix Central (April 2015). 2) Verify your certificate configuration in the Worklight Server: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/admin/r_ssl_certificate_keystore_setup.html

Comment: Also mention if this is being tested in a remote server (if so, what is the application server configuration), or in the development server in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You do not explain in the question how was the certificate set-up on the server side. It could be that the certificate configuration was set to expire after 365 days (1 year).

The following are Worklight 6.2 user documentation topics that you should read through thoroughly and then see if you need to adjust your certificate set-up:

- [SSL configuration](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.monitor.doc/monitor/c_user_CA_SSL.html?lang=en)
- [SSL certificate keystore setup](http://SSL%20certificate%20keystore%20setup)
- [Configuring SSL between Worklight adapters and back-end servers](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/t_configuring_SSL_WL_adapters_backend_servers_certificates.html?lang=en) (note the example with setting up validity days)

Comment: The certificate being tested are not expired. I'm studying the links that provided and will further update here. Thanks Idan.

Comment: I'm not saying that the certificate expired, but that the setup was set to 1 year.